# Solve $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{ e^{ -\frac{1}{2} \frac{\rho}{\beta} (t - j \alpha \frac{\rho}{\beta})^{2} }}{(t-j \rho)^{M} (t+j \rho)^{M}} dt$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, complex-integration, residue-calculus, chain-rule

I want to solve the integral:

$$ f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{ e^{  -\frac{1}{2} \frac{\rho}{\beta} (t - j \alpha \frac{\rho}{\beta})^{2} }}{(t-j \rho)^{M} (t+j \rho)^{M}} dt $$

where $j$ is the imaginary unity, with $ \beta, \rho \in \mathbb{R}_{++}$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$. The numerator is simply a complex Gaussian, with a peak at $t = j \alpha \frac{\rho}{\beta}$, which is analytic. If we take a contour in the upper half plane, encircling $t = j \rho$, then we know as the radius of our contour $R \rightarrow \infty$, we have that the numerator  $e^{  -\frac{1}{2} \frac{\rho}{\beta} (t - j \alpha \frac{\rho}{\beta})^{2} } \rightarrow 0$.

Our integral therefore reduces to:
$$ f(x) =j \cdot \text{Res}(z = j \rho) $$

The residue is:

$$ \text{Res}(z = j \rho) = \underset{z \rightarrow j \rho}{\text{lim}} \frac{1}{(M-1)!} \frac{d^{M-1}}{dz^{M-1}} \left[ (z-j\rho)^{M} \frac{ e^{  -\frac{1}{2} \frac{\rho}{\beta} (z - j \alpha \frac{\rho}{\beta})^{2} }}{(z-j \rho)^{M} (z+j \rho)^{M}}  \right] $$

$$ \text{Res}(z = j \rho) = \underset{z \rightarrow j \rho}{\text{lim}} \frac{1}{(M-1)!} \frac{d^{M-1}}{dz^{M-1}} \left[\frac{ e^{  -\frac{1}{2} \frac{\rho}{\beta} (z - j \alpha \frac{\rho}{\beta})^{2} }}{ (z+j \rho)^{M}}  \right] $$

We can compute this residue using the Generalized Leibniz rule:

$$ \frac{d^{M-1}}{dz^{M-1}} [ p(z) \cdot q(z)] = \sum_{k=0}^{M-1} \binom{M-1}{k} \frac{d^{M-1-k}}{dz^{M-1-k}} p(z) \cdot \frac{d^{k}}{dz^{k}} q(z)  $$

with $p(z) = (z+j \rho)^{M}$ and $q(z) = e^{  -\frac{1}{2} \frac{\rho}{\beta} (z - j \alpha \frac{\rho}{\beta})^{2} }$

---

**Question:**

Is there a simpler way? I know I can evaluate $\frac{d^{k}}{dz^{k}} e^{  -\frac{1}{2} \frac{\rho}{\beta} (z - j \alpha \frac{\rho}{\beta})^{2}}$ via Faa di Bruno's formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula) or via the method presented here (http://www.m-hikari.com/ams/ams-2012/ams-73-76-2012/oliveiraAMS73-76-2012-1.pdf).

Doing either gives me a complicated mess though. Is there a simpler way? Is this a standard integral of any type? Am I missing an obvious simplification?

Thanks!

Comment: you can not apply residue theorem this way. the integrand explodes as soon as the argument of the quadritc term in the exponent enters the sector $\pi/2\pm \delta$ with $ 0 \leq \delta <\pi/4$ of the complex plane...

Comment: @asgeige So you're saying the numerator isn't entire?

Comment: @asgeige Okay, I see what you are saying. Let $\delta = 0$, then the exponent is $e^{-j \frac{\beta}{\rho}R^{2}}$ so as $R \rightarrow \infty$, the integrand oscillates infinitely often. So what do I do instead?

Comment: i thaught we integrate over t... but yes something like this or worse happen (the realpart can become positive)

Comment: Sorry, I let $-\frac{1}{2} \frac{\rho}{\beta} (t - j \alpha \frac{\rho}{\beta})^{2} = R e^{j \frac{\pi}{2}}$, solved for $t$, and then plugged the solution back in to the quadratic term in the exponent to see what happened. This is when the oscillatory bx appeared, because when we take the contour in the upper half plane, we let $R \rightarrow \infty$, and this makes this explosion happen.

Comment: @asgeige So what can I do to solve this integral instead?

Comment: @asgeige Wait, I think we applied the ML theorem wrong here. In the upper half plane, as $R \rightarrow \infty$, shouldn't the denominator ensure that the integrand $\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: along the imaginary axis the exponaential grows faster then polynomial in the denominator decays...

Comment: @asgeige Right. Letting $t = jR$ and plugging in shows this. We get an exponential that grows without bound as $R \rightarrow \infty$. Damn! Back to the drawing board...

Comment: at least the case of $\alpha=0$ should be solvable by differentiation under the integral sign and the solution of the differential equation which surfaces afterwards

Comment: Assume $\rho \alpha /\beta <1$ then we can shift the integration contour above the real axis without changing anything (otherwise we pick up some a resiude, which we already calculated) and the method from above should work again

Comment: @asgeige If you post that solution, I will give you the answer credit.

Comment: @asgeige I was thinking that I would let $z = t - j \alpha \frac{\rho}{\beta}$, and then create a rectangular contour underneath the real axis. We will still have a residue, but I think this should avoid the blowing up error.

Comment: Too busy sorry... but look for goodwin staton integral and thelike...
https://dlmf.nist.gov/search/search?q=Goodwin%E2%80%93Staton%20integral

Comment: @asgeige Okay I will take a look at that. Not sure how to fit my problem into that mould, but I'll figure it out eventually Im sure.

Comment: if you pick up the residue or not should depend on the values of your parameter....

Comment: @asgeige Indeed it will depend on the parameters. I was thinking the same thing. That is how I will solve this guy.

Comment: There is some singularity in the denominator via
$\displaystyle\left(t - j\rho\right)^{M}$.

Comment: @FelixMarin Yes that is true. Thank you for pointing that out. It was very helpful.